# Waiting for one of the elements in the list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code of waitinf for one element:

```
public WebElement waitElement(String selector) {
        WebElement element = wait.until((WebDriver d) -> d.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)));
        return element;
}
```

I have a grid with table. So I always wait for the appearance of rows. 
But I have a problem if the table is empty. In this case I have in the grid an element of the "no-data_grid" class .

So the question is how to wait for one of these two elements?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cssSelector` or `,` to wait for one of them

```
public WebElement waitElement(String firstLocator, String secondLocator) {
    WebElement element = wait.until((WebDriver d) -> d.findElement(By.cssSelector(firstLocator + ", " + secondLocator)));
    return element;
}
```

This will return when the driver manage to locate one of the elements.

You could also use the `or` expected condition

```
wait.until(
    ExpectedConditions.or(
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(firstLocator)),
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(secondLocator))
    )
);
```

Comment: "no-data_grid" is not in the table. When the table is empty it isn't exist in the grid.

Comment: So I have a table OR an element of class "no-data_grid" in the grid. NOT both.

Comment: I don't need to find it. I need to wait it. Because it means that all elements were loaded.

Comment: @BerasMark In your question and your first comment you wrote that if the table is empty you have the `no-data_grid` element. Now you are saying you have it when all the elements are loaded. Which is it?

Comment: Okay. I have a page and a grid on it. The page was loaded if the grid was loaded. Grid can consist of a table OR an element of the "no-data_grid" class. So I have to wait for one of them.

Comment: In my question I said that I know how to wait for one element. But how I can  change my function or write smth similar if I want to wait for one of two elements?

Comment: the first solution doesn't work. cssSelector() expect only one String as input value

Comment: @BerasMark my bad, concat the strings with the `,` `By.cssSelector(firstLocator + ", " + secondLocator)`